# como puedo resolver este problema de interfaz grafica de unity no carga completamente

Tags: unity3d

[image: Interfaz Grafica de unity no se carga completamente], Saludos a todos! , espero que me puedan ayudar con el software unity que me sale con problemas en la interfac grafica he intentado todo desde desinstalar y volver instalar unity , he borrado los archivos temporales para volver a reinstalarlo.

Comment: Bienvenido Edilson... podrías mostrarnos exactamente cual es el error??? necesitamos mas información para poder ayudarte.... mientras tanto podrías darte una vuelta por [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y evitar puntuaciones negativas o reportes...

Comment: saludos Victor Hugo, el error ocurre cuando cargo la interfaz de unity el cual le faltan algunos componentes que no se muestran y no puedo acceder a ellos.